# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Issue with uiGmapMarker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i using `angular-google-maps 2.2.1` in my application and i have a list '`itemStatusData`' which have objects contain information of lat and lng . When i push first element of my list to marker my location get update perfectly but when the size of my list which contains lat lng related data increases and when i try to push only single element it gives me error:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at baseClone (lodash.js:1686)
    at lodash.js:1734
    at lodash.js:3073
    at baseForOwn (lodash.js:2046)
    at baseClone (lodash.js:1733)
    at lodash.js:1734
    at lodash.js:3073
    at baseForOwn (lodash.js:2046)
    at baseClone (lodash.js:1733)
    at lodash.js:1734
```

i have following code which gets the list of lat lng data from server

```
$scope.play = function(){                   
                $scope.carCurrentStatusData = [];

                $q.when(Item.findItemGPSLocationHistory({itemid: itemid}).$promise, function(data){                        
                    $scope.itemStatusData = data;                    
                });
            }
```

ItemStatusData have objects of lat and lng

In my html i am using this code:

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
     <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" idkey="marker.id">

     </ui-gmap-marker>
   </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

code which fills marker data is

```
$scope.fillMarkerData = function(value, data){
              $scope.map = { center: { latitude: data.lat, longitude: data.lng }, zoom: parseInt($scope.zoom) };
              $scope.markers = [];
              var marker = {
                id: value,
                coords: {
                  latitude: data.lat,
                  longitude: data.lng
                }
              };
              $scope.markers.push(marker);
        };
```

Here i also want to add that if my list which contains lat lng data increase above 1980 then it throws above error below this it is running fine. I do not know what is happening.

I also want to add one more clue that i have a watch expression. if i removed that watch expression then my code works fine otherwise it fails. If any one can help me then please help.

Comment: **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded** means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit. Check this related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735083/settimeout-and-jquery-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded). Maybe the problem is your call to `setTimeout` is invoking `getNum` instead of scheduling it for execution.